# read basic auth user/pass with CGI script?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, cgi, fastcgi, basic-authentication

I´m facing a problem right now with apache basic auth and my CGi script.

Does anyone know if it is possible to read the user/pass from the basic auth with a CGi script?

What I want to accomblish is that the user logs in via apache basic auth and starts a CGI stript.
The CGI script get the user/pass from the basic auth login and does something else with it (starting a child process).

Is it possible to get the user/pass from a CGI script?
Or can I do this with some fancy rewrite rule or pass it with the CGI call?

I hope that someone can answer this because I dont really know a alot about apache/rewrite rules and even if it is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: out of interest, what does `base64 -d <<< "${HTTP_AUTHORIZATION#Basic }" | sed -n -e 's/^[^:]*:\(.*\)$/\1/p'` (or similar, if you're doing CGI in something other than bash) yield?

Comment: *to be clear, [Basic Authentication would be available via the `Authorization` HTTP header](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7617#section-2)—at least, [it might be](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875#section-9-2), depending on how the server's configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution... not perfect but I´m getting close.

Its possible to write a external authenticator for Apache using mod_authn_external.

See: https://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/

The basic auth credential get passed (piped or ENV vars) to the script/prog and then its possible to do some magic.

I want to authenticate with perl and PAM, but PAM is not working yet, refer to my question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629123/get-authen-pam-working-with-perl-apache

Hope this helps someone...